# numpy.unique changes NULL character to empty character

Tags: python, numpy

**EDIT:**
I rephrased the question in terms of *bytes* rather than *characters*.  I am doing a frequency analysis on ciphertext.

---

When I use `numpy.unique()` on a list of bytes, the NULL byte `b'\x00'` ends up being the empty character `b''`
.

The following minimal example

```py
import numpy as np

byte_list = [b'\x00', b'1']
freq = {byte: count for (byte, count) in zip(*np.unique(byte_list, return_counts=True))}
freq
```

returns

```py
{b'': 1, b'1': 1}
```

while I expect

```py
{b'\x00': 1, b'1': 1}
```

Why is that?

Python version `3.7.4`.
Numpy version `1.17.2`.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Try `bs = b'\\x001'`

Answer (score 1):

If this is your expected output:

```
{b'0': 2, b'1': 1, b'\\': 1, b'x': 1}
```

You forgot about the backslash`(\)` that escapes the next character in your `bs` variable. In this case `bs` will be:

```
bs = b'\\x001'
```